# MySQL can't get data between 2 dates

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql view in the database for this query. The column that the date field is in is set to a varchar type.

The dates range from 01/13/2021 - 09/18/2021.

%VAR2% = 01/01/2020
I also set %VAR2% to other dates, but the current one that is not working for me is 11/28/2020. It is returning a no values at all.

I have tried numerous ways to set t1.procedureDate, %VAR2%, & %CURRENT_DATE% to be dates in mysql, but nothing works when I put those in and the values stay the same as when the table first gets loaded. Any ideas on how I could make this work?

The following query is the one that I am using to get data based upon the specified date range.

```
t3.traineeName, 
    t3.procedureDate,
    t3.surgeryID,
AVG(NULLIF(t3.traineeRemovesFatAdrenalRating, 0)),
AVG(NULLIF(t3.traineeSkeletonizesRenalVeinRating, 0)),
AVG(NULLIF(t3.traineeSkeletonizesArteryRating, 0)),
AVG(NULLIF(t3.traineeDonorArteriesRating, 0)),
AVG(NULLIF(t3.traineeRenalVeinAugmentationRating, 0)),
AVG(NULLIF(t3.traineeTissuePerformanceRating, 0)),
AVG(NULLIF(t3.traineeAnatomyPerformanceRating, 0)),
AVG(NULLIF(t3.traineeProcedurePerformanceRating, 0)),
AVG(NULLIF(t3.doctorRemovesFatAdrenalRating, 0)),
AVG(NULLIF(t3.doctorSkeletonizesRenalVeinRating, 0)),
AVG(NULLIF(t3.doctorSkeletonizesArteryRating, 0)),
AVG(NULLIF(t3.doctorDonorArteriesRating, 0)),
AVG(NULLIF(t3.doctorRenalVeinAugmentationRating, 0)),
AVG(NULLIF(t3.doctorTissuePerformanceRating, 0)),
AVG(NULLIF(t3.doctorAnatomyPerformanceRating, 0)),
AVG(NULLIF(t3.doctorProcedurePerformanceRating, 0))
FROM 
(SELECT
    t1.traineeName, 
    t1.procedureDate, 
    t1.surgeryID,
    t1.traineeRemovesFatAdrenalRating,
    t1.traineeSkeletonizesRenalVeinRating,
    t1.traineeSkeletonizesArteryRating,
    t1.traineeDonorArteriesRating,
    t1.traineeRenalVeinAugmentationRating,
    t1.traineeTissuePerformanceRating,
    t1.traineeAnatomyPerformanceRating,
    t1.traineeProcedurePerformanceRating,
    t2.doctorRemovesFatAdrenalRating,
    t2.doctorSkeletonizesRenalVeinRating,
    t2.doctorSkeletonizesArteryRating,
    t2.doctorDonorArteriesRating,
    t2.doctorRenalVeinAugmentationRating,
    t2.doctorTissuePerformanceRating,
    t2.doctorAnatomyPerformanceRating,
    t2.doctorProcedurePerformanceRating
  FROM
    BackbenchKidneyChartTrainee t1
  JOIN
    BackbenchKidneyChartDoctor t2 
  ON
     t1.traineeName = t2.traineeName
  WHERE
    t1.surgeryID = t2.surgeryID
  AND 
    (t1.traineeName = "%VAR1%" AND t2.traineeName = "%VAR1%")
  AND t1.procedureDate BETWEEN %VAR2% AND '%CURRENT_DATE%' ) t3
```

Comment: Have you tried ISO date format, eg `'2020-11-28'`, which [the date format mysql uses](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)? Note that USA is the only (significant) country in the world that uses dates like `11/28/2020` - that's why it's called the "American" date format.

Comment: it alo not a good idea to use VARCHAR to store a date. in this case mysql must read all rows and convert it -> **FULL TABLE SCAN** and cant use a index. you can convert it like SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01/13/2021','%m/%d/%Y'); result : 2021-01-13